# How to install Haskell cabal tool for Haskell 7.6.1 on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, haskell, installation

I installed Haskell on MAC OSX according to the instructions on this page.

Version 7.6.1
http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_1

However, it does not install the cabal tool which I need for installing packages.

How can I install cabal?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the top of [that page](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_1):

> ## Stop!
>
> For most users, we recommend installing the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) instead of GHC. The current Haskell Platform release includes a recent GHC release as well as some other tools (such as cabal), and a larger set of libraries that are known to work together.

So following [that link](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) will get you what you want: [the Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) is GHC plus [the packages and tools you want](https://web.archive.org/web/20210414235837/https://www.haskell.org/platform/contents.html), including Cabal (the library) and cabal-install (the command-line tool).  Since you're on OS X, you can also use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to get the GHC and Cabal if you want: `brew install ghc cabal-install`.

Comment: Homebrew no longer supports `haskell-platform` and insists that you install `ghc` and `cabal-install`. It should be noted that `cabal` isn't able to find `-lgmp`; still trying to resolve this. Will edit if I find a fix.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon: Definitely good to mention.  That said, though, is there a reason you can't just download the Haskell Platform [from the website](http://www.haskell.org/platform/)?  It's even up to date (GHC 7.8.3) now!

Comment: Managed to fix it: http://pemungkah.com/xmonad-on-os-x-mavericks/. Being able to "just install" with "brew install" and "cabal" is easier.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon ah ! i had this pb and thought i was the only one !

Comment: can you tell more about what was going on and what fixed it ?

Comment: `export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/X11/lib` was what did the trick so `cabal` could find the libraries it needed.

Comment: Whats your suggestion when one needs to compile against older (today) version of ghc (<= 7.6), and needs appropriate versions of Cabal etc - all that on macOS Sierra? :D

Comment: @Mati: Well clearly you are not "most users"! :-)  Unfortunately, I have no idea beyond that.  You might try asking a new question here if you have something concrete, or posting something on [/r/haskell](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell) or a similar place if you just want advice.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky Thanks for advice! Im quite close - went with Vagrant, older Debian box and manually built both GHC & Cabal. (packages for older Debian releases are mostly deleted from their repositories).

Answer (score 1):

Now, we can install it from this [download haskell](https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html) and do not need homebrew. Both are easy ways.

Answer (score 0):

As the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) is deprecated since 2022, Haskell on Mac can be installed using Homebrew.

The [Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC)](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/) and [The Cabal Library](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/developing-packages.html) can be installed using:

```
brew install ghc cabal-install
```

To install the [The Haskell Tool Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) use:

```
brew install stack  --cask
```