# c2hs installation error with Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: haskell, cabal, c2hs

I'm trying to install c2hs with `cabal install c2hs`.
I created `~/.cabal/bin` to install the binary beforehand.

With the command `cabal install c2hs` to get the errors.

```
src/Control/StateTrans.hs:77:1: Warning:
    Module `Prelude' does not export `catch'
[ 3 of 26] Compiling Data.Errors      ( src/Data/Errors.hs, dist/build/c2hs/c2hs-tmp/Data/Errors.o )
[ 4 of 26] Compiling Data.Attributes  ( src/Data/Attributes.hs, dist/build/c2hs/c2hs-tmp/Data/Attributes.o )
[ 5 of 26] Compiling Text.Lexers      ( src/Text/Lexers.hs, dist/build/c2hs/c2hs-tmp/Text/Lexers.o )
[ 6 of 26] Compiling Control.StateBase ( src/Control/StateBase.hs, dist/build/c2hs/c2hs-tmp/Control/StateBase.o )
[ 7 of 26] Compiling Data.NameSpaces  ( src/Data/NameSpaces.hs, dist/build/c2hs/c2hs-tmp/Data/NameSpaces.o )
[ 8 of 26] Compiling C2HS.C.Attrs     ( src/C2HS/C/Attrs.hs, dist/build/c2hs/c2hs-tmp/C2HS/C/Attrs.o )
[ 9 of 26] Compiling C2HS.C.Builtin   ( src/C2HS/C/Builtin.hs, dist/build/c2hs/c2hs-tmp/C2HS/C/Builtin.o )
[10 of 26] Compiling Paths_c2hs       ( dist/build/autogen/Paths_c2hs.hs, dist/build/c2hs/c2hs-tmp/Paths_c2hs.o )

dist/build/autogen/Paths_c2hs.hs:21:13: Not in scope: `catch'

dist/build/autogen/Paths_c2hs.hs:22:13: Not in scope: `catch'

dist/build/autogen/Paths_c2hs.hs:23:14: Not in scope: `catch'

dist/build/autogen/Paths_c2hs.hs:24:17: Not in scope: `catch'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
c2hs-0.16.5 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

What is wrong with the installation? The ghc version is 7.6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I installed two different versions of ghc on my mac: one from `brew install ghc` and the other from [haskell platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/).

I had to install the newest version of haskell platform, but before doing that I also needed to uninstall old version `uninstall-hs only VERSION` and `brew unistall ghc`.

After reinstalling the newest haskell platform,  the compilation works fine.

- https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1137
- [How to install Haskell cabal tool for Haskell 7.6.1 on Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239289/how-to-install-haskell-cabal-tool-for-haskell-7-6-1-on-mac-osx)

Other method can be using brew `brew install haskell-platform`.

Answer (score 1):

The install worked for me right now, on my Ubuntu box, so I can say for sure that c2hs isn't broken for everyone right now.

I think you might have version issues....  Try

```
cabal update
```

and try the install again.

In particular-

The function Prelude.catch was moved to Control.Exception.catch recently, see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4865.  I downloaded the c2hs sources (using cabal unpack c2hs), and looked at what headers Paths_c2hs.hs needs (this seems to be the file with the import problems).  This is what the imports section contained-

```
import qualified Control.Exception as Exception
import Data.Version (Version(..))
import System.Environment (getEnv)
import Prelude
```

(Paths_c2hs.hs is autogenerated, so I had to build it first).

Indeed, it was using Control.Exception.  Because this is a module in base, you should have it, and probably just have out of date/mismatched packages.  (In fact, my file's line numbers don't match your error message line numbers above- This is another indication we are using different versions, and I believe mine is up to date :) .)

Although I think that the "cabal update" will fix the problem, if not, try looking in these two places-

1. Does Control.Exception.catch exist in your base modules? Just try to compile an empty program with an dummy reference to catch, like this-

   import Control.Exception

   x = catch

   main = undefined
2. Does your autogenerated Paths_c2hs.hs point to the correct catch function.  Just use cabal to unpack, configure and build c2hs and then look at dist/build/autogen/Paths_c2hs.hs.  (you will probably hit your error in the build phase, but given what you have shown above, it will happen after the Paths_c2hs.hs creation).