# How to install Haskell on Mac OS

Tags: macos, haskell, installation

I am trying to install Haskell on my Macbook two days and can not get the success.

What I have done:

```
$ brew install ghc
```

Fine.  Now I am trying to install

```
$ cabal install text
```

and get next error messages:

```
Data/Text.hs:1074:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^
```

I have googled and found [this](https://gist.github.com/pyrtsa/6213784).

So:

- brew install gcc48

  ```
  $ /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8 --version  
  gcc-4.8 (GCC) 4.8.2
  Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
  warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

  $ cat /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.6.3/settings
    [("GCC extra via C opts", " -fwrapv"),
     ("C compiler command", "/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8"),
     ("C compiler flags", " -m64 -fno-stack-protector  -m64"),
     ...
  ```
- brew install cabal-install
- cabal install text

And I get the same messages.

How can I fix them ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using the [Mac version of the Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html),  I don't have a Mac to try it out but my hope is that `cabal` will work out-of-the-box in the Haskell Platform.

Comment: "The Haskell Platform is deprecated since 2022 and is no longer the recommended way of installing Haskell. For the latest recommended way to install Haskell please see the Downloads page."

Comment: This should no longer be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 61):

`brew install ghc cabal-install`

If you prefer homebrew.

**Note:** *(Edited to add)* Homebrew may have an older (or newer) version of ghc than the Haskell Platform download for OSX, and there might be other differences. You [can check the release notes here](https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html) for the version included in Haskell Platform, as well as other information of interest. `brew info ghc cabal-install` will give you up to date information about Homebrew's versions.

**Note:** The last time I did this, I just installed haskell-stack instead, as described in Filippo's answer.

Comment: `brew info` was helpful!

Comment: Prepare to have your computer burning for 30-60 minutes onces you do this, this compiles like forever. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247096/99834 for doing it in two minutes by installing binaries.

Answer (score 49):

To install the "Haskell Stack" binaries via `homebrew`:

```
brew install haskell-stack
```

---

**EDIT**: Below my original answer

> If you want to install the `Haskell Platform` binaries via homebrew:
>
> ```
> brew install cask
> brew cask install haskell-platform
>
> cabal install cabal-install
> ```

Comment: This is what [Haskell.org](https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html#osx-homebrewcask) says to do [instead of installing GHC with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239289/how-to-install-haskell-cabal-tool-for-haskell-7-6-1-on-mac-osx).

Comment: As of 05/2020: `Error: Cask 'haskell-platform' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

Comment: Well @Indigenuity times has passed, the command is now: `brew install haskell-stack` Thanks for the headsup, I have updated my answer

Comment: this now returns "Error: `brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead." when running brew cask install haskell-platform

Answer (score 14):

The following information suggests there may be a mac installer available:

```
brew info haskell-platform

We no longer package haskell-platform. Consider installing ghc
and cabal-install instead:

brew install ghc cabal-install

A binary installer is available:
https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html
```

Comment: Nowadays it shows three components: ghc, cabal-install and haskell-stack

Answer (score 9):

In 2022, [the Haskell Platform is deprecated](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) and [the officially recommended way for most platforms](https://www.haskell.org/downloads/), including Mac, is to install [GHCup](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/) first. `GHCup` is basically a package manager for the Haskell toolchain (`GHC`, `Stack`, `Cabal`, `HLS`). It can install multiple versions of each of these into the home directory, and "set" (symlink) the `ghc`/... commands to a specific version.

To install `GHCup`, use the install script ([source](https://gitlab.haskell.org/haskell/ghcup-hs/-/blob/master/scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap-haskell)). This installs `GHCup` and `GHC`, asks some questions about setting up PATH etc., and prompts you to install the Apple developer command line tools if it notices them missing.

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
```

If you're on a Mac M1 and want to run `ghc` 8.10.7 or older, you will also need to install a version of `llvm` between 9 and 12 (inclusive), and put it on the path so `ghc` can find it. Currently however, 9.2.4 is the default, which has a native code generator (NCG) that works on M1 out of the box. It may still contain bugs on M1 though (see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/qg1g2g/comment/hi4as1y/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) for details) so consider upgrading to 9.4.2 with `ghcup install ghc 9.4.2 && ghcup set ghc 9.4.2`. Currently, 9.4.2 lacks the breadth of package support enjoyed by 8.10.7, but it is has fewer known bugs.

---

If you find yourself in an install mess, you can start from a clean slate and reinstall both the Developer Tools and `GHCup` with:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
ghcup nuke
rm -rf ~/.ghcup
rm -rf ~/.stack
rm -rf ~/.cabal
# For the cautious, a reboot here is advised before proceeding
xcode-select --install
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
```

---

It's also possible to install `GHCup` via Homebrew, though that requires to manually update $PATH and install/set the wanted tools.

```
brew install ghcup
# Now add $HOME/.ghcup/bin to $PATH
ghcup install ghc && ghcup set ghc
```

Comment: This is the answer today, and will save hours. `ghcup` will also play nicely with editors/plugins/etc and the Haskell Language Server to ensure you have the right bits and the right versions. See `ghcup list` for insight into the important tool management it does for you.

One gotcha though - ghcup's installs and ghcup itself install into your home directory, so maybe not quite what you'd expect.

Comment: To be fair on M1 this only got me as far as `ghci` and `hls`. To use `ghc` I still needed to run `brew install llvm@12` and then add `/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@12/bin` to the `PATH`. And even then that only results in a successful *compile* - even the simplest of "Hello world" programs still hang forever when executed after compilation, and then `ghcup install` and even `gcc` compiled executables also hang. So consider this only a partial solution for now!

Comment: Ah ha! Finally got a full solution. tl;dr: ghc 8.10.7 (the recommended, and default installed version) is a dead end on a M1 Pro. But 9.4.2 works fine without having to resort to llvm shenanigans. I'd like to suggest an edit to your answer @konst to include this info.

Comment: Oh dear. The hanging was not entirely llvm related. Inexplicably, if I compile and run a Haskell program on a network drive, it hangs. And from **that point on** any `ghc`/`gcc` compiled executable hangs, local or otherwise, until reboot! Preposterous, but reporting here before I have a bloody clue what's going on, so my edit to this answer is given reference.

Comment: Finally made amends. Confident now that ghc 8.10.7 requires llvm on M1 and 9.2+ works without it. Since 9.2.4 is now the default, GHCup works out of the box. Retained the useful information in the answer and deleted the rest.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new [ghc-dot-app](https://github.com/ghcformacosx/ghc-dot-app) project that is an alternative to Homebrew formula and Haskell Platform official installer.  Here is the project's web page: [Haskell for Mac OS X](http://ghcformacosx.github.io).  Here is a discussion thread about it on [Haskell Cafe](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haskell-cafe): "[Self-contained GHC for Mac](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/haskell-cafe/mac/haskell-cafe/0j8-0-bnz7I/5I5mcuqtPPwJ)".  Here is a quote from the author's posting:

> How does it work?
>
> In https://github.com/ghcformacosx/ghc-dot-app I have a Main.hs script
>   which downloads/builds/etc. all of the prerequisites. Then it patches
>   the shell scripts to use a path relative to themselves (after
>   following symlinks) rather than hard-coding an installation location.
>   It also patches the package.conf.d files to use ${pkgroot} relative
>   paths.
>
> Separately, there's an Xcode project that includes all of the metadata
>   to make it look like a real Mac app bundle (icons, Info.plist) and a
>   small Cocoa application that has a button to open the docs and
>   provides instructions for adding it to the PATH in .bashrc. Due to the
>   heuristics in Mac OS X's man, this will automatically make man pages
>   work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Haskell using `brew install haskell-platform`.

If you are already on Mavericks you will have to install GCC (as Mavericks ships with Clang). Follow the instructions here: https://gist.github.com/cartazio/7131371.

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely the magic incantation for `homebrew` users.

Comment: Unfortunately, `haskell-platform` is no longer supported via `homebrew`, at least as of Sept. 8, 2014.  See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/31609

Comment: @nonrectangular Yes, `haskell-platform` has been removed from `homebrew`, but it is available from [homebrew cask](http://caskroom.io). Just installed using `brew cask install haskell-platform`

Comment: Might it have been removed for a reason? If so, perhaps it's not actually advisable to install the cask'd version.

Comment: `brew install ghc cabal-install haskell-stack`